# sharing data between 2 component in react. no parent child relation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-context

I have 2 `component` in react. for ex `Producer.js` and `Consumer.js.` . there is no `parent` `child` relationship between them.

I need to set one variable in `Producer.js` and consume that value in `Consumer.js`

I searched in google and tried using `context API` but it is not working. I am new so not able to resolve the issue.

so in `producer.js`.

```
 const Name = createContext(false);
  const [isActive,setIsActive]=useState(false);
  <Name.Provider value={isActive}>
            </Name.Provider>
```

and in consumer.js I am trying to consume `isActive`.

```
  <Name.Consumer value={isActive}>
        alert(isActive);
    </Name.Consumer>
```

it is not compiling.

it is not able to even recognize `isActive` or `value` in `Consumer.js`. what wrong I am doing?.
you can also suggest if there is better way.

**Edit:-1**
I have actually 2 component in Menu tab.
User and
Inventory.
I need to display User if value is true otherwise it should not display.

```
<span >
          <Link to="Inventory">List of Inventory</Link>
 </span>
 <span>
         <Link to="user">List of User</Link>
 </span>
```

I want  `<Link to="user"> User</Link>` this to display when value is `true`. otherwise it should be false.

```
 <Name.Consumer>
    {value => 
        
      <span className="badge badge-white">
    { value && <Link to="user"> List of Users</Link> }
    </span>
    }
    </Name.Consumer>
```

.

`List of Users`  tab displaying whether value is `true` of `false`. How can I modify the code?

Comment: share you code in codesandbox or add error that you are facing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The consumer doesn't access the context value like a prop, it's accessed as a child function component:

[Context.Consumer](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextconsumer)

> ```
> <MyContext.Consumer>
>   {value => /* render something based on the context value */}
> </MyContext.Consumer>
> ```

For your consumer example, it would look similar to the following:

```
<Name.Consumer>
  {value => {
    console.log(value);
    return value ? "Active": "Inactive";
  }}
</Name.Consumer>
```

It is more common now to use the `useContext` hook in a function component though. Example:

```
const isActive = useContext(Name);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(isActive);
}, [isActive]);

return isActive ? "Active": "Inactive"
```

Comment: actually I modified my code but I am not able to get exact functinalty which I want. I have modified question in Edit section. could you please have a look?

Comment: @ShrutiSharma I created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharing-data-between-2-component-in-react-no-parent-child-relation-2zife7) with your code and the context appears to toggle and conditionally render the link in a consumer without issue. If you're unable to resolve this can you create a codesandbox of your own that reproduces the issue that we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: Hey Drew, thank you so so much . it worked. thank you so much for offering extended help.I might need sometime in future. you are the person with golen heart. thank you Drew.